# How is Botframework v3 buils using react.In create-react-app we start from index.jsand how do we integrate custom build in create react app

Tags: reactjs, botframework

**Botframework-webchat** : https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/v3

I want to know how Botframework is build using react,so i can understand and custom code it.Also want to know how to integrate it in create-react-app

**What i have tried**

I read the botframework documentation and tried adding it using dependency by setting up path to build botframework file and run npm install.I get error sayng package.json is missing in that file.

Want to add  custom build botframework in create-react-app.Also want to know which file should i start in botframework (like index.js in create-react-app)

Comment: Regarding building a custom version of BotFramework, can you provide any pertinent code / commands you have tried and the related error(s)?

Comment: As for building it into the create-react-app, you will have to explore that. Performing a custom build still produces the botchat.css and botchat.js files to be consumed by a webpage. Integrating the core Web Chat code into another project is not what the code was designed for. Additionally, this question is too broad and should be about a specific issue you hare experiencing.